# Does setting a Firebase value to the same value use bandwidth?

Tags: firebase

Firebase:

```
{exampleValue: "something";}
```

Javascript:

```
var ref = new Firebase(url + "/exampleValue");
ref.set("something");
```

I have a couple of questions around setting a value in Firebase to the same value, as shown above.

1. Does it use bandwidth for the user?
2. Does it count towards the bandwidth for my Firebase plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: calling `set()` multiple times with the same value will use bandwidth each time.

You can easily test these things yourself. I just did the following: open the "Network" tab in the Chrome developer tools and find the WebSocket ("WS") that communicates with Firebase. In the "Frame" tab of that web socket you can see exactly what the Firebase client communicates with its server.

Then run the following in the developer console:

```
  var newRef = ref.push();
```

This generates a new path/location, but does not send anything to the Firebase servers yet. Then:

```
  newRef.set('This is a value');
```

This sets the value, so uses bandwidth.

Then I ran the same again:

```
  newRef.set('This is a value');
```

This once again sent data to the Firebase server, so it uses bandwidth.

When you think about it, this also makes sense. The Firebase client knows only its local state. The value on the server might be different, for example because somebody else has changed the value. So when you tell it to set the value, it must send that command to the server to ensure that value actually gets written into the database.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  For some reason up until now I thought it didn't, I think I got mixed up with the only downloading data once for reading data multiple times.